# Fresh install, volume is too low even at 100%

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio, pop-os

So I decided to try out pop_os (20.10) and after some minor problems everything is working now, except the audio. Even at 100% volume is too low! I used to be able to set my headset on the desk and still hear everything even when standing 2-3 meters away but now the only way to listen to anything is with my headset on and even then the volume seems too low, about 60-70% of the volume I have on my earbuds, enabling over-amplification seems to somewhat help but the audio quality is of course terrible. I tried toying around with pavucontrol, alsamixer and qasmixer, turning everythin to 100% but no luck. I also tried installing various music players (rhythmbox,clementine,pharga) just in case they come with drivers but nothing changed. I'm starting to suspect that maybe it has something to do with motherboard drivers? If that's the case, what can I do since they are only available for windows?

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

PS: Headset is connected to mobo audio jack, also tried front panel.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu can be tricky for audio.. if not done so already try using the following:

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio
```

Comment: This is not a good solution.  I'm trying to rediscover an asound.conf file that will create a "pre-amp" that allows the user to boost the audio output.